# spyder4 takes a long time to open

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Spyder 4 for Python development. I notice that it takes a very long time (sometimes even 2 long minutes) to load.

I have read that this issue existed in earlier versions of Spyder and is now "resolved" in Spyder 4.

Is anyone else facing the same problem?

If yes, what steps would you recommend to overcome this problem?

I have tried `spyder --reset` and do not see any significant improvement.

Comment: Weird. This could just be to do with your system specification I suppose. I have not seen any slowness in mine loading. Has this been happening lately or has it been the case the whole while?

Comment: Hello @AzyCrw4282, I have a good system having 16 GB RAM. Other than Spyder and Chrome, usually nothing else runs on my laptop. The first load itself had taken longish time. Of late, it has worsened.

Comment: Tried the good old uninstall & reinstall method?